# Reloading tableview in Promisekit's then

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, promisekit

I am trying to make async. request using Promisekit's promises. I have the following code in a subclass of UITableViewController, to reload tableview with data that is fetched from async. request.

```
my_promise.then { asynly_fetched_data in 
  self.data = asyncly_fetched_data
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

However, the following statement (self.tableView.reloadData()) is causing the following build error.

```
 Missing return in a closure expected to return 'AnyPromise'
```

Is it because we cannot call reloadData() inside a closure. IF that is the case, what is the best practice to reload tableview after asynchronous request is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a swift bug. But you can fix it by adding `-> Void` in your closure:

```
my_promise.then { asynly_fetched_data -> Void in 
  self.data = asyncly_fetched_data
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

That way, Swift knows that the return is Void.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked. But how did you figure it out that (-> Void) fixes the issue.

Comment: It's a known bug. I've had a similar problem before.

Comment: it's not a bug - it's how multiline closures works - compiler cannot infer return type from you code and compare it with requirement from method definition. if you left only one line - it will compile normally